# Mod rewrite to get expression in url as parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite a url. I want to enter this url in the browser:

```
 localhost/subDir/page-name/value1/value2
```

and then read value1 en value 2 into a querystring, so like this:

```
localhost/subDir/page-name/?firstArg=value1&secondArg=value2
```

This is for a wordpress website. The wordpress is installed in a subdirectory, called "subDir". The wordpress page is called 
page-name" and going to localhost/subDir/page-name works. The standard permalinks are working, so mod_rewrite is enabled. This is my .htacces file

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /subDir/

RewriteRule page-name/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? page-name/?firstArg=$1&secondArg=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /subDir/index.php [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What is `page-name` in reality ? An existing file (or folder) ?

Comment: It is really page-name (just using this for testing service). But it is not an existing file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_rewrite does not consider the query string as part of the URI for matching
and rewriting, It should be treated separately.

```
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "^firstArag=([^=]*)&secondArg=([^=]*)
RewriteRule "/subDir/index.php" "http://localhost/subDir/page-name/%1/%2" [R]
```

[R] indicates to direct to URL constructed by the RewriteRule directive

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand rewriterules correctly, but are you sure this isn't the other way around? That i have to enter ?firstArg... into the browser and that i get redirected to page-name/value1/value2?

I am trying to do the opposite

Comment: This code does the opposite of what is asked. Besides, there are syntax errors (why using double quotes ?)

Comment: @JustinIurman I realized that. I am really sorry for that. I just wrote it without testing it. I read it from apache cookbook having it on desk. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your current code by this one

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /subDir/

   RewriteRule ^page-name/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ page-name/?firstArg=$1&secondArg=$2 [L]
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```